# Association belongs_to :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I know that isn't any belongs_to :through association in Rails, but how could I work around it?

- `User` model has many `Batches`
- `Batch` model has many `Forecasts`

I want to create an association stating that a `Forecast` belongs to a `User`. However, I understand that since a `Forecast` already belongs to a `User`, it shouldn't be necessary to store `used_id` inside `Forecast` model.

How can I create this relationship between `Forecast` and `User` through the `Batch` model?

**EDIT**

Let me better explain my problem.

I have the following models and associations:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :batches
# has_many :forecasts, through: :batches
end

Batch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :forecasts
end

Forecast < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :batch
# belongs_to :user, through: :batch
end
```

The commented lines is what I want to do, but I cannot, since there is no `belongs_to :through` association.

The relationship is strictly what is said on the code: a User may have many batches. A batch is a set of forecasts, so a Batch may have many forecasts. Since a Batch must belong to a User, and a Forecast must belong to a Batch, then a Forecast belongs to a User.

I want to get select all Forecasts that belongs to all Batches from a User.

```
current_user.forecasts
```

The reason I want to do that, is to limit the scope of a user only to its own batches and forecasts. So on controller actions, instead of

```
Batch.find(params[:id])
```

or

```
Forecast.find(params[:id])
```

I can make

```
current_user.batches.find(params[:id])
```

or

```
current_user.forecasts.find(params[:id])
```

It is already possible to do that with Batch. Forecasts, on the other hand, doesn't belongs_to a user yet. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* `has_many :through` in Rails. You can check out [the Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) to see how to use it.

Comment: Indeed, however it works slightly different from my needs. In that case, one only model stores both id's from the association. I need that Forecast has a batch_id, and that Batch has a user_id. And I need to create a relationship between User and Forecast through Batch.

Comment: I have changed the title and the question. Actually I was speaking about belongs_to through. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your User model:

```
has_many :batches
has_many :forecasts, :through => :batches
```

In your Batches model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :forecasts
```

In your Forecasts model:

has_many :batches
   has_many :users, :through => :batches

That last line is just if you want the relationship to go both ways, like a full many-to-many relationship.